# How to whilelist specific IP addresses from AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

We have a web application which is protected by aws WAF. Our company network are blocked more often than not due to reach the threshold. We have a team working with the web app, of course we are much easier to reach the threshold.

So, I want to whilelist our company public IP addresses from aws WAF, which is controled/maintained by company Global team. And the feedback I got was that there was no such functionality.

Is there any possible way to whilelist (or bypass) aws WAF for spcific IP addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already configured Rate base rule, so you need slightly different changes to **allow unlimited request from the office IP** and block request when originated from other IPs when they hit the limit.

- Create an IP match condition for your Office Ip

[image]

- Create [Rate base rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-how-aws-waf-works.html) with limit and set condition when does not originate from IP sets that we created on step 1

Add this rule in the Web ACL.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course you can do this. You would want the default behaviour of your WAF to be block all.

Then create a [IPSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_IPSet.html). You can add your office IP address within this.

Finally attach this to your WAF and set it to "Allow". Ensure this is the **top rule**, it will be **evaluated first** ignoring all other rules.

For more information take a look at [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-ip-set-managing.html) for creating and managing an IPSet.